# bootstrap button dropdown not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

The dropdown buttons on my webpage are not updating properly on mobile.  When someone selects an entry from the dropdown, that entry should populate the main dropdown selector.   Works as intended on desktop (and mobile simulator in Chrome), but does not on mobile phones.

HTML can be seen at the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/axpjadda/2/

Javascript below

```
$(function() {
  $('#dropdown1-pills a').on('touchstart', function(){    
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($(this).html()+' was touched');  
  })
  $('#dropdown1-pills a').on('click', function(){    
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($(this).html()+' was clicked');    
  })
  $('#dropdown2-pills a').on('click', function(){    
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().html($(this).html()+' was clicked');    
  })
});
```

Comment: may be this ll helps you https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4550